# Why are console.log() and alert() returning different information?

Tags: javascript, fetch, filereader

I have the following code in JavaScript that takes a URL pointing to a image, and uses `fetch()` along with `FileReader()` to get the image's data as a data URL.

```js
fetch(document.getElementById("image-url").value).then(res => res.blob()).then(data => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        alert(this.result.toString());
        console.log(this.result.toString());
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
});
```

However, what `alert()` returns is different from what `console.log()` returns. (I tried to include the image data for both `alert()` and `console.log()`, but it won't let me as they're too long.)

When I load the image data from `alert()` in my browser, it returns "Invalid URL", while the second returns the original image data(i.e, it works). What am I missing? I'm planning to upload this image data to a server for later use, but the data that gets uploaded is the same as `alert()`, which isn't very useful.

Answer (score -1):

`alert()` can only process strings.
`console.log()` can process objects and strings.

[console.log() vs. alert() when debugging](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/js/console-log-vs-alert-when-debugging/)

```js
const foo = {};
alert(foo);
```

Comment: `.toString` in OP's code makes me think that the source of this issue is different. The question misses information on that, and as such, it isn't prossible to answer properly.

Comment: `this.result` is a string though, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result).

Comment: @detectiveCamel: What caused the "Invalid URL" message with alert()?

Comment: Run the snippet I added for you. `alert` accepts any argument with a `toString()` method. The article you linked points out that while you can alert objects, the output generated if logging via console.log is more useful.

Comment: @JohnH browsers can typically take image data formatted as a data URL and output a image. When I tried to view the image data `alert`ed, my browser returned "Invalid URL". When I tried to view the image data logged though, the image popped up just fine.